# Contest code for a maze problem

Tags: java, optimization, programming-challenge, pathfinding

I would like to ask your comments on my contest code for the following problem:

We're going to have a slightly more logical puzzle today. We're going to write a program that will find a path through a simple maze.

> **Formal Inputs & Outputs**
>
> **Input Description**
>
> Through standard console,
>   you will be given two numbers X and Y. After that you will be given a
>   textual ASCII grid, X wide and Y tall, of walls # and spaces. In the
>   maze there will be exactly one letter S and exactly one letter E.
>   There will be no spaces leading to the outside of the maze - ie. it
>   will be fully walled in.
>
> **Output Description**
>
> You must print out the maze. Within the maze there
>   should be a path drawn with askerisks * leading from the letter S to
>   the letter E. Try to minimise the length of the path if possible -
>   don't just fill all of the spaces with *!
>
> **Sample Inputs & Outputs**
>
> ```
> Sample Input 15 15
> ###############
> #S        #   #
> ### ### ### # #
> #   #   #   # #
> # ##### ##### #
> #     #   #   #
> # ### # ### ###
> # #   # #   # #
> # # ### # ### #
> # # # # # #   #
> ### # # # # # #
> #   #   # # # #
> # ####### # # #
> #           #E#
> ###############
>
>
> Sample Output
> ###############
> #S**      #   #
> ###*### ### # #
> #***#   #   # #
> #*##### ##### #
> #*****#   #   #
> # ###*# ### ###
> # #***# #   # #
> # #*### # ### #
> # #*# # # #***#
> ###*# # # #*#*#
> #***#   # #*#*#
> #*####### #*#*#
> #***********#E#
> ###############
> ```

I coded my solution in Java. I would like to ask on possible improvements on my solution such as parts I can optimize. Any other comments regarding the code is also very much appreciated as my purpose of posting this is to improve my coding skills.

```
public class Solution {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Solution sol = new Solution();
                sol.solve();

        }

        public Solution() {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        }

        private void solve() {
                int[] inputs = convertStringArraytoIntArray(nextLine().split(" "));
                int x = inputs[0];
                int y = inputs[1];
                char[][] maze = new char[y][x];
                for (int ctr = 0; ctr < y; ctr++) {
                        maze[ctr] = nextLine().toCharArray();
                }
                Maze inputMaze = new Maze(maze);
                int maxMoves = inputMaze.numOfSpaces();
                HashSet<Maze> seenMazes = new HashSet<>();
                Stack<Maze> mazeStack = new Stack<>();
                mazeStack.add(inputMaze);
                Maze answer = null;
                while (mazeStack.size() > 0) {
                        Maze currMaze = mazeStack.pop();
                        if (seenMazes.size() > 300000)
                                break;
                        if (currMaze.isSolved()) {
                                if (answer == null || answer.getMoves() > currMaze.getMoves()) {
                                        answer = currMaze;
                                }

                        } else {
                                if (currMaze.getMoves() < maxMoves) {
                                        if (currMaze.canMoveUp()) {
                                                Maze temp = currMaze.moveUp();
                                                if (!seenMazes.contains(temp)) {
                                                        mazeStack.push(temp);
                                                        seenMazes.add(temp);
                                                }
                                        }
                                        if (currMaze.canMoveDown()) {
                                                Maze temp = currMaze.moveDown();
                                                if (!seenMazes.contains(temp)) {
                                                        mazeStack.push(temp);
                                                        seenMazes.add(temp);
                                                }
                                        }
                                        if (currMaze.canMoveLeft()) {
                                                Maze temp = currMaze.moveLeft();
                                                if (!seenMazes.contains(temp)) {
                                                        mazeStack.push(temp);
                                                        seenMazes.add(temp);
                                                }
                                        }
                                        if (currMaze.canMoveRight()) {
                                                Maze temp = currMaze.moveRight();
                                                if (!seenMazes.contains(temp)) {
                                                        mazeStack.push(temp);
                                                        seenMazes.add(temp);
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                answer.print();
        }

        private int[] convertStringArraytoIntArray(String[] strArray) {
                int[] intArr = new int[strArray.length];
                for (int ctr = 0, len = strArray.length; ctr < len; ctr++) {
                        intArr[ctr] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[ctr]);
                }
                return intArr;
        }

        private int nextInt() {
                try {
                        return Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
                } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return 0;
                }
        }

        private String nextLine() {
                try {
                        return bufferedReader.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
        }
}

public class Maze {

        public int moves;
        private char[][] maze;
        private Point currLoc;
        private Point endPoint;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public Maze(char[][] maze) {
                this.maze = maze;
                moves = 0;
                height = maze.length;
                width = maze[0].length;
                currLoc = findStart();
                endPoint = findEnd();
        }

        public int numOfSpaces() {
                int numOfSpaces = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                                if (maze[y][x] == ' ' || maze[y][x] == 'E') {
                                        numOfSpaces++;
                                }
                        }
                return numOfSpaces;
        }

        private Point findStart() {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                                if (maze[y][x] == 'S') {
                                        return new Point(x, y);
                                }
                        }
                return null;
        }

        private Point findEnd() {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                                if (maze[y][x] == 'E') {
                                        return new Point(x, y);
                                }
                        }
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                Maze secondMaze = (Maze) obj;
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                                if (maze[y][x] != secondMaze.elementAt(y, x)) {
                                        return false;
                                }
                        }
                return true;
        }

        private char elementAt(int y, int x) {
                return maze[y][x];
        }

        public boolean canMoveUp() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                if (y > 0 && maze[y - 1][x] != '#' && maze[y - 1][x] != '*') {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
                return height;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
                return width;
        }

        public Maze moveUp() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                Maze temp = createClone();
                temp.setElementAt(y - 1, x, '*');
                temp.setCurrentLocation(y - 1, x);
                temp.setMoves(moves + 1);
                return temp;
        }

        private void setMoves(int moves) {
                this.moves = moves;
        }

        private void setCurrentLocation(int y, int x) {
                this.currLoc = new Point(x, y);
        }

        private void setElementAt(int y, int x, char c) {
                maze[y][x] = c;
        }

        private Maze createClone() {
                char[][] newMaze = new char[height][width];
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                                newMaze[y][x] = maze[y][x];
                        }
                return new Maze(newMaze);
        }

        public boolean isSolved() {
                if (currLoc.x == endPoint.x && currLoc.y == endPoint.y) {
                        maze[currLoc.y][currLoc.x] = 'E';
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        public int getMoves() {
                return moves;
        }

        public boolean canMoveDown() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                if (y < height - 1 && maze[y + 1][x] != '#' && maze[y + 1][x] != '*') {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        public Maze moveDown() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                Maze temp = createClone();
                temp.setElementAt(y + 1, x, '*');
                temp.setCurrentLocation(y + 1, x);
                temp.setMoves(moves + 1);
                return temp;
        }

        public boolean canMoveLeft() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                if (x > 0 && maze[y][x - 1] != '#' && maze[y][x - 1] != '*') {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        public Maze moveLeft() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                Maze temp = createClone();
                temp.setElementAt(y, x - 1, '*');
                temp.setCurrentLocation(y, x - 1);
                temp.setMoves(moves + 1);
                return temp;
        }

        public boolean canMoveRight() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                if (x < width - 1 && maze[y][x + 1] != '#' && maze[y][x + 1] != '*') {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        public Maze moveRight() {
                int x = currLoc.x;
                int y = currLoc.y;
                Maze temp = createClone();
                temp.setElementAt(y, x + 1, '*');
                temp.setCurrentLocation(y, x + 1);
                temp.setMoves(moves + 1);
                return temp;
        }

        public void print() {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                                System.out.print(maze[y][x]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
        }
}
```

Lastly, the line `seenMazes.size() > 300000` is a dirty way to ensure that the program terminates after spending time searching possible solutions and might also cause answer to be null if ever no answer has been obtained yet. I found it difficult to calculate the maximum number of possible outcomes based on the input alone and also due to time constraint.

Comment: @Manny Meng Thank you for your comment, I did not check for possible exceptions during input because the rules of the contest stated that the inputs will always be correct. Also I needed to code fast since contests are about speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Code Style

Your code is actually not bad.  However, I would modify the general OO structure.

- I would separate the Maze from its representation.  There would be a `MazeTextRepresentation` which would read in text to create a `Maze` and a method to print out a `Maze` as text.  This is standard "separation of concerns"; here we separate the model from its representation.  You can later create a JavaFX `MazeGUIRepresentation` without having to modify your existing code at all.  Related to this point: you really should not read in the `Maze` in your `Solution` class, but just give it a `Maze`.
- I would rename `Solution` to `PathFindingAlgorithm` and actually make it an interface instead of a class.  The interface would have only one method that takes a `Maze` and returns a path.  You should also define a class `Path`.  For example, your current solution would be `public class BruteForceAlgorithm implements PathFindingAlgorithm`.

## Algorithm

As I just alluded above, the algorithm you are using is a brute force (exhaustive search) algorithm.  It is not efficient.  You could not scale this algorithm for large mazes.  Take a look at [path finding algorithms on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding).  The A* algorithm is the one usually used in video games.

You could also improve your current algorithm a little bit.  You have very many `Maze`s which you use to store different paths, but it would be more efficient to define a `Path` class and use a `Stack<Path>` instead of `Stack<Maze>`.   You could change class `Maze` so that it only contains a `boolean[][]` (wall or empty).  It could not contain a `Path`, but that is no big deal since you just need to combine a `Maze` and a `Path` at the very end to display the solution as text, or maybe on a GUI.

Comment: Accepted because of suggestions on how to improve the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself

You have this duplicated code for evaluating each direction:

> ```
> if (currMaze.canMoveUp()) {
>     Maze temp = currMaze.moveUp();
>     if (!seenMazes.contains(temp)) {
>         mazeStack.push(temp);
>         seenMazes.add(temp);
>     }
> }
> ```

It would be good to create an `enum Move` to represent all the possible moves. And instead of functions like `canMoveUp`, create a more general function that takes a `Move` as its argument, like `canMove(Move move)`, and use a loop to evaluate all the moves.

---

Likewise, the code of `findStart` and `findEnd` are almost identical. You could easily generalize and implement the logic in one place.

#### Practical issues

The `equals` method should check the class of its parameter, typically in this form:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Maze) {
        // the real comparison to the other Maze goes here
    }
    return false;
}
```

This has the added benefit of preventing class cast exception and null pointer exception.

---

Declare variables with their interface types instead of the implementation.
For example instead of:

> ```
> HashSet<Maze> seenMazes = new HashSet<>();
> ```

Do like this:

```
Set<Maze> seenMazes = new HashSet<>();
```

---

This `if` statement can be simplified:

> ```
> if (y > 0 && maze[y - 1][x] != '#' && maze[y - 1][x] != '*') {
>     return true;
> }
> return false;
> ```

Like this:

```
return y > 0 && maze[y - 1][x] != '#' && maze[y - 1][x] != '*';
```

You have this in every `canMoveX` method.

---

The way you copy the `char[][]` array can be improved:

> ```
> for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
>     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
>         newMaze[y][x] = maze[y][x];
>     }
> ```

Like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    System.arraycopy(maze[y], 0, newMaze[y], 0, width);
}
```

---

You have some unused methods:

- `getHeight`
- `getWidth`
- `nextInt`

There's no need to speculate about potential future uses. Implement methods when you actually use them. Every line of code may potentially introduce bugsis potentially buggy.

#### Coding style

When checking the size of a `Stack`, instead of this:

> ```
> while (mazeStack.size() > 0) {
> ```

Do like this:

```
while (!mazeStack.empty()) {
```

---

It's recommended to use braces with `if` statements, so instead of:

> ```
> if (seenMazes.size() > 300000)
>     break;
> ```

Do like this:

```
if (seenMazes.size() > 300000) {
    break;
}
```

The same goes for the outer `for` loop in the `equals` method.

Comment: Thank you for the coding tips. They are very much appreciated. I'll try to apply them.